# List<Map<String,dynamic>> to List<String> Dart

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I am new to programming. I have a List<Map<String,dynamic>> of data and I want to create a List of Strings from map values. Here is my sample data. Let's say I need a list of product names in Dart. Appreciate your help.Thanks.

```dart
final products = [  
     {'productimage': 'image1.jpg', 'productprice': '800', 'productid': '1234', 'productname': 'rabbittoy'},
     {'productimage': 'image2.jpg', 'productprice': '400', 'productid': 'p10001', 'productname': 'mousetoy'},
     {'productid': '4533', 'productprice': '1800', 'productimage': 'image3.jpg', 'productname': 'cat'},
     {'productname': 'dog', 'productid': 'p10002', 'productimage': 'image4.jpg', 'productprice': '3000'}
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `fold` method:

```
  List<String> productNames = data.fold<List<String>>(
      [], (prev, element) => List.from(prev)..add(element['productname']));
```

Full snippet example:

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
    {
      'productimage': 'image1.jpg',
      'productprice': '800',
      'productid': '1234',
      'productname': 'rabbittoy'
    },
    {
      'productimage': 'image2.jpg',
      'productprice': '400',
      'productid': 'p10001',
      'productname': 'mousetoy'
    },
    {
      'productid': '4533',
      'productprice': '1800',
      'productimage': 'image3.jpg',
      'productname': 'cat'
    },
    {
      'productname': 'dog',
      'productid': 'p10002',
      'productimage': 'image4.jpg',
      'productprice': '3000'
    }
  ];

  List<String> productNames = data.fold<List<String>>(
      [], (prev, element) => List.from(prev)..add(element['productname']));
  print(productNames); // [rabbittoy, mousetoy, cat, dog]
}
```

Comment: Works as I expected. Timely help. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your list was assigned to a variable called `products` I would use `.map()` to do the following:

```dart
final productNames = products.map((Map<String, dynamic> product) {
  return product["productname"];
}).toList();
```

I'm using `.toList()` at the end because `.map()` returns an `Iterable` object rather than a `List` object. I couldn't give you a 100% answer on why but you can read about it [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/iterables-and-iterators-in-dart-e670b74c3ddf).

Comment: Will give a try. Thank you!